# Do ovaries produce estrogen before menarche?

Tags: reproduction, endocrinology, sex

It is traditionally taught that estrogen is produced by the granulosa cells of the follicle. But before menarche, where does the estrogen come from? Is it from the thin layer of granulosa cells lining the primordial follicles?
The adrenal zona reticularis produces androgens physiologically. Are they converted to estrogen? If yes, by whom? If not by the ovary, would the levels of estrogens be same in prepubertal boys and girls?

More importantly, are there estrogens in a girl before menarche? If yes wouldn't they cause endometrial changes?

Comment: It would be better to break this into two individual questions.

Comment: @Polisetty one possibility-pre pubertal FSH release follows a circadian rhythm and this concentration is so little that only very sensitive methods could detect this rhythm...as menarche approaches the frequency and amount of FSH release increases & hence also oestrogen...so endometrial changes would not be possible before menarche.